# How can i keep only one class of my variable in a histogram in SAS?

Tags: sas, histogram, where-clause

I have this histogram:

[image]

But I want to have only the upper portion (owned). What should I add to my code?

My code is this:

```
proc univariate data=data3; 
var HHincome; 
class Ownership;
HISTOGRAM ; 
run;
```

Comment: FYI - there's a free SAS beginner course here if you're interested: https://support.sas.com/ecprg1

Answer (score 3):

Add a WHERE statement to filter the results to just the one category.

```
proc univariate data=data3; 
where ownership = 'OWNED';
var HHincome; 
class Ownership;
HISTOGRAM ; 
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc univariate data=data3 (where=(Ownership = 'OWNED')); 
var HHincome; 
class Ownership;
HISTOGRAM ; 
run;
```